# Validating Uri from String

Tags: .net, validation, uri

I need an Uri validation method. So, strings like:

"http://www.google.com",
"www.google.com",
"google.com"

..must be validated as Uri's. And also normal strings like "google" must not be validated as Uri's. 
To do this checking, I use two methods: UriBuilder and Uri.TryCreate().

The problem with UriBuilder is that any string I give it, it returns an Uri out of it. When I pass a normal string in its constructor, it gives it a scheme and returns "http://google/" which is not the behavior I want.

The problem with Uri.TryCreate() is that, while it works ok with "http://www.google.com" and "www.google.com", when I give it "google.com" it does not validate is as an Uri.

I thought about doing checks on the string, if it starts with http:// or www, send the string to the UriBuilder class, but this does not help with "google.com" which also must be an Uri.

How can I validate stuff like "google.com" as an Uri, but not "google"? Checking the end of the string for .com, .net , .org doesn't seem flexible.

Comment: can you verify whether you are looking to validate a URL or a URI? Your question is somewhat confusing.

Comment: @Slugster - after reading your question I checked online to understand teh difference so the answer is that I need to validate a URI, not URL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public static bool IsValidUri(string uriString)
{
    Uri uri;
    if (!uriString.Contains("://")) uriString = "http://" + uriString;
    if (Uri.TryCreate(uriString, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out uri))
    {
        if (Dns.GetHostAddresses(uri.DnsSafeHost).Length > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The protocol can be [several other things](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Examples_of_absolute_URIs) other than HTTP.

Comment: @slugster: That's why he checks if it already has a protocol... he only sets it to http if it doesn't.. which is by far the most common and is pretty safe to default to.

Comment: Thank you for your code. However this code builds an Uri from a single word - if I pass "google" i get in return "http://google/" which is not what I need. Also I would like to avoid building the code logic on try/catch constructs.

Comment: @andrei: Sounds like you need both a Uri Validator and a DNS checker. I updated the function to include both, and removed the try/catch.

Comment: Thank you for the updated code. By the way you can replace strings "://" and "http" with their object correspondents Uri.SchemeDelimiter and Uri.UriSchemeHttp. The problem with this code is that when the string is normal like "google", it throws a SocketException. So I have made a variation of your code that handles it:

Comment: I think adding the protocol string should be out of this function's scope.

Answer (score 19):

What you're looking for is `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString`. The following code returns true:

```
Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("google.com", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
```

If you set UriKind to Absolute, it returns false:

```
Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("google.com", UriKind.Absolute)
```

EDIT:
See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.urikind.aspx) for UriKind enumeration.

- RelativeOrAbsolute:  The kind of the Uri is indeterminate.
- Absolute:    The Uri is an absolute Uri.
- Relative:    The Uri is a relative Uri.

From [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.urikind.aspx):

> Absolute URIs are characterized by a complete reference to the resource (example: http://www.contoso.com/index.html), while a relative Uri depends on a previously defined base URI (example: /index.html).

Also, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring.aspx) for `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString`. This method works in accordance with RFC 2396 and RFC 2732.

If you look at [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt), you'll see that google.com is not a valid URI. In fact www.google.com isn't neither. But under **F. Abbreviated URLs**, this situtation is explained in detail as follows:

> The URL syntax was designed for unambiguous reference to network
>      resources and extensibility via the URL scheme.  However, as URL
>      identification and usage have become commonplace, traditional media
>      (television, radio, newspapers, billboards, etc.) have increasingly
>      used abbreviated URL references.  That is, a reference consisting of
>      only the authority and path portions of the identified resource, such
>      as
>        www.w3.org/Addressing/
>      or simply the DNS hostname on its own.  Such references are primarily
>      intended for human interpretation rather than machine, with the
>      assumption that context-based heuristics are sufficient to complete
>      the URL (e.g., most hostnames beginning with "www" are likely to have
>      a URL prefix of "http://").  Although there is no standard set of
>      heuristics for disambiguating abbreviated URL references, many client
>      implementations allow them to be entered by the user and
>      heuristically resolved.  It should be noted that such heuristics may
>      change over time, particularly when new URL schemes are introduced.
>      Since an abbreviated URL has the same syntax as a relative URL path,
>      abbreviated URL references cannot be used in contexts where relative
>      URLs are expected.  This limits the use of abbreviated URLs to places
>      where there is no defined base URL, such as dialog boxes and off-line
>      advertisements.

What I understand from that is, `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString` accepts strings that are in form of www.abc.com as valid URIs. But google.com is not accepted as an absolute URI whereas it's accepted as a relative URI because it conforms to relative path specification (paths can contain .).

Also, as a side note, if you want to use regular expression to parse a URI, you can read **B. Parsing a URI Reference with a Regular Expression**.

Comment: thank you for your answer. This method is interesting, it does validate "google.com" which is great, however it validates a single word ("google") as a well formed uri as well, which I don't need. Helpful answer nonetheless

Comment: @Andrei: I've updated my answer. The answer lies in RFC 2396.

Comment: Thanks for this, I have further read about Uri.IsWellFormedUriString and I think I understand why it validates "google" as a valid Uri. So, what I need I guess, is a way to check if the end of the string has a .com, .net, ..etc attached to it. I am reluctant of using Regular Exp on this because they can have flaws, what if in the future someone invents a popular extension like ".zedo" for example, my regExp will not catch it since it will only handle known terminations (.net, .com etc).

Comment: @Andrei: Regular expressions may get you in trouble in the future as you mentioned. So, sticking with standard methods provided by the framework is better. I suggest you insert http:// to the beginning of the string, if it doesn't start with it.So that http://google.com becomes an absolute URI.

Answer (score 3):

this is a variant of the code from Jojaba to whom I thank for the DNS checker, that was what I needed. the only problem is that it uses a try catch in its logic which I was hoping to avoid.

```
        public static Uri StringToAbsoluteUri(string uriString) 
        {
        Uri resultUri = null;

        if (!uriString.Contains(Uri.SchemeDelimiter))
            uriString = Uri.UriSchemeHttp + Uri.SchemeDelimiter + uriString;

        if (Uri.TryCreate(uriString, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out resultUri))
        {
            try
            {
                IPAddress[] addressesOfHost = Dns.GetHostAddresses(resultUri.DnsSafeHost);
                if (addressesOfHost.Length > 0)
                {
                    return resultUri;
                }
            }
            catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }   
        return resultUri;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

use RegExp for this.

Sample code of validation URL

```
Regex RgxUrl = new Regex("(([a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z+\\-\\.]*:)?/{0,2}[0-9a-zA-Z;/?:@&=+$\\.\\-_!~*'()%]+)?(#[0-9a-zA-Z;/?:@&=+$\\.\\-_!~*'()%]+)?");
    if (RgxUrl.IsMatch(<yourURLparameter>))
    {
      //url is valid
    }
    else
    {
      //url is not valid
    }
```

Comment: To use this regular expression on an old POSIX Extended Regular Expression I had to move the hyphen-minus character to the end of the matching groups[]. For example, un-escaped, "^(([a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z+.-]*:)?/{0,2}[0-9a-zA-Z;/?:@&=+$._!~*'()%-]+)?(#[0-9a-zA-Z;/?:@&=+$._!~*'()%-]+)?$"